# Is LittleEndianDataInputStream known to be unstable especially on Linux?

Tags: java, stream

I recently took over development of a telemetry software for a Formula Student car. It uses Java8 and JavaFX8. There is one major bug I am trying to fix right now but I am completely stuck at the moment.
The program can load the logged data in a custom format later to review. This is working fine on Mac and Windows but is causing trouble on Linux. Some distros manage to load the data sometimes and some distros do not manage it at all. The problem could be related to LittleEndianDataInputStream.

I do not get the whole problem yet. So I was wondering if someone could show me some way to "debug" or getting behind this kind of problem. And tell me if using LittleEndianDataInputStream (not implemented by me) is a good idea or not (Even IntelliJ is marking this API as unstable). If not what would be a suitable alternative to use?
The code is always reaching the "Loader Exeption" from "readVersion()" because of wrong version number. Loading the same file from Windows works fine.

Might

```
private static Set<Integer> SUPPORTED_VERSIONS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        1 << 16
    ));
```

be calculated differently on operating systems ?

For Example Fedora is causing the ErrorLog (every time) at the end. The related code is below.

```
private static Set<Integer> SUPPORTED_VERSIONS = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        1 << 16
    ));
```

....

```
public long readTimestampFromHeader(File file) throws LoaderException
    {
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                   LittleEndianDataInputStream input = new LittleEndianDataInputStream(bis))
        {
            bytesRead.set(0);
            readVersion(input, file);
            input.readUnsignedShort();  // ID
            readString(input);          // Name
            readString(input);          // Type
            return input.readLong();
        }
        catch(EOFException e)
        {
            // File corrupt, much too short. Simply ignore
            log.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not read record header. Ignoring ...", e);
            return 0L;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            throw new LoaderException(file, e);
        }
    }

private void readVersion(LittleEndianDataInputStream input, File file) throws IOException, LoaderException
    {
        int version = input.readInt();
        bytesRead.set(bytesRead.get() + 4);

        if(!SUPPORTED_VERSIONS.contains(version))
        {
            throw new LoaderException(file, new Exception("File version "
                    + version + " is not supported"));
        }
    }
```

Interesting parts of ErrorLog:

```
de.***.***.loader.LoaderException: The loader failed loading from /home/****/****/****/****/***/***/01 - 05.06.2018/Logfiles/1970-01-01-01-01-08/brake_pressure-front.ebl
    at de.***.***.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readVersion(EboxLogReader.java:155)
    at de.***.***.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readTimestampFromHeader(EboxLogReader.java:130)
```

.....

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: File version 83946924 is not supported
```

**EDIT:**
Summing up the things I tried from suggestions in comments or myself and it's effects:

- Manually adding the missing version from ErrorLog -> File is loaded into GUI without error but is called 08.01.105917131 instead of "xyz.ebl" and unusable
- Updating the dependency of com.google.guava API to later releases does not change anything
- Simply swapping LittleEndianInputStream to ObjectInputStream produces same ErrorLog but with Version:256
- The file I am trying to load seems to be written as ObjectOutputStream and is being read by LittleEndianInputStream. This seems strange but only Linux has difficulties with it. Writing the file (which I am trying to load) is done here:

```
public class DataRecordSerializer implements Serializer<DataRecord, FileDataLocator>
{
    public static final int VERSION = (0 << 16) + (1 << 8) + 0;

    private final boolean append;

    public DataRecordSerializer()
    {
        this(false);
    }

    public DataRecordSerializer(boolean append)
    {
        this.append = append;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(DataRecord data, FileDataLocator locator) throws SerializerException
    {
        File target = locator.getFile();
        boolean actuallyAppends = this.append && target.exists();

        // Save the data
        try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target, this.append);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            ObjectOutputStream out = actuallyAppends ?
                    new AppendingObjectOutputStream(bos) :
                    new ObjectOutputStream(bos))
        {
            if(!actuallyAppends)
            {
                // Version info
                out.writeInt(VERSION);

                // Save the concrete class
                out.writeUTF(data.getClass().getName());

                // Header
                out.writeObject(data.getHeader());
            }

            // Data
            float[] x = data.getXValues();
            float[] y = data.getYValues();

            for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            {
                out.writeFloat(x[i]);
                out.writeFloat(y[i]);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            throw new SerializerException(e);
        }
    }

    public static class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream
    {
        public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
        {
            // do not write a header, but reset
            reset();
        }
    }
}
```

- Changing the Supported_Version to Value from DataRecordSerializer

```
public static final int VERSION = (0 << 16) + (1 << 8) + 0;
```

does not change anything. Afterwords I kept this as Supported_Versions and swapped LittleEndianInputStream and ObjectInputStream again and got this ErrorLog:

```
 java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:3106)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1076)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readString(EboxLogReader.java:158)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readTimestampFromHeader(EboxLogReader.java:127)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogLoader.load(EboxLogLoader.java:65)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogLoader.load(EboxLogLoader.java:24)
    at de.*.loader.LoaderManager.load(LoaderManager.java:122)
    at de.*.model.DataManager.forceLoadRunData(DataManager.java:193)
    at de.*.model.DataManager.getRunData(DataManager.java:218)
    at de.*.gui.fx.job.runData.LoadRunDataJob.call(LoadRunDataJob.java:22)
    at de.*.gui.fx.job.runData.LoadRunDataJob.call(LoadRunDataJob.java:8)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
WARNING - 26.06.19 19:32:24: Could not read record header. Ignoring ...
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:3106)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:1076)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readString(EboxLogReader.java:158)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogReader.readHeader(EboxLogReader.java:52)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogLoader.load(EboxLogLoader.java:86)
    at de.*.loader.ebl.EboxLogLoader.load(EboxLogLoader.java:24)
    at de.*.loader.LoaderManager.load(LoaderManager.java:122)
    at de.*.model.DataManager.forceLoadRunData(DataManager.java:193)
    at de.*.model.DataManager.getRunData(DataManager.java:218)
    at de.*.gui.fx.job.runData.LoadRunDataJob.call(LoadRunDataJob.java:22)
    at de.*.gui.fx.job.runData.LoadRunDataJob.call(LoadRunDataJob.java:8)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**EDIT**
Bug was not fixed unfortunately but difficulties disappeared after redesigning this part of the application, thanks again for all contributions.

Comment: 83946924 can be written in hexadecimal as 0x0500EDAC.  The bytes `ac ed 00 05` are the signature of a Java serialization stream.  If you write a file with ObjectOutputStream, you have to read it with ObjectInputStream.

Comment: The config files (like restoring layout )for this project are stored by using ObjectOutputStream. So you suspect the program trying to read ObjectOutputStream with LittleEndianDataInputStream? Yeah this can not work. I will dig into that. Thanks so far

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 0):

SUPPORTED_VERSIONS is initialized with no elements, and and initial value 1<<16.
You could debug, or try:

```
static {
    SUPPORTED_VERSIONS.add(83946924);
}
```

You did not show the filling of SUPPORTED_VERSIONS, where a concurrency, class loading error might happen, due to concurrency. AFAIK Linux for instance has better concurrency support. Maybe the initialisation happens in a second class, and the class loading goes wrong.

83946924 is 0x500_EDAC, which contains a byte 0x00, but I cannot imagine such a C-like bug, or String related modified UTF-8 conversion where 0x00 is also turned into a multibyte sequence.

Maybe the version was itself wrong and should have been 0xACED_0005.

BTW The exception can simply be written less tricky as:

```
        throw new LoaderException("File version "
                + version + " is not supported: " + file);
```

Alternative classes:

You can use a memory mapped file, using `ByteBuffer` with `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`. This is standard java.

Comment: Actually `1 << 16` is an element, not the capacity.  It’s `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1 << 16))`, not `new HashSet<>(1 << 16)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, just tried that. I can not provide the filling of SUPPORTED_VERSIONS because as far as I can tell right now it stays for it's initial value. Adding it manually is giving me an object called "08.01.105917131" which can not be used inside the GUI at all. The object should be called "xyz.ebl". Had a quick look at @VGR suggestion, too and this might actually really happen. Will get back when I had time to dig into that completely. Thank you so far to both of you!

Comment: You mentioned you cannot image C like bugs - I have to add the values inside the software and which are stored in these .ebl files actually come from the board computer which ist written in C and is connected via UDP.

Comment: At this stage I can only make wild guesses. I think @VGR is more on the right track. Maybe try a file name without blanks (though that would be weird).